# Wrong output when using a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calculates the price something.
When the age < 5 then price = 0,
when the age < 15 the price = price/2
and when age > 15 the price = price + price*0.15. The first 2 are working fine but the last one has a problem. When for example a put 100 on the price input and 26 on the age input the answer that it gives me is 10015.

```
<script>
  function add(x, y) {
    return x+y;
  }
  function Subtract(x, y) {
    return x-y;
  }
  function Divide(x, y) {
    return x/y;
  }
  function Multiply(x, y) {
    return x*y;
  }
  var plusPrice = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
  })();
  var plusButton = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
  })();
  function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = plusButton();
    if (document.getElementById("price").value !== '') {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = plusPrice();
    }
  }
  function checkInputs() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if( parseInt(price) < 0  ||  isNaN(parseInt(price))) {
      window.alert("Please insert a valid price");
      price = '';
    }
    if(parseInt(age) > 100 || parseInt(age) < 0 ||  isNaN(parseInt(age))){
      window.alert("Please insert a valid age");
      age = '';
    }
  }
  function Calculate() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if (document.getElementById("price").value !== '' && document.getElementById("age").value !== '') {
      if (age<5) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Subtract(price,price);
      } else if (age < 15 && age >= 5) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Divide(price,2);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add(price,Multiply(price,0.15));
      }
    } else {
      window.alert("Please fill both age and price to calculate the amount you have to pay");
    }
  }

</script>

<body>
    Please enter the price: <br>
    <input type="text" id="price"><button onclick="document.getElementById('price').value = ''">Clear input field</button><br><br>
    Please enter your age: <br>
    <input type="text" id="age"><button onclick="document.getElementById('age').value = ''">Clear input field</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="checkInputs(); updateClickCount(); Calculate();">Calculate price</button>
    <p id="totalPrice">The total amount you have to pay is: </p><br>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p>Button Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
    <p>Correct Price Fill Count: <span id="input">0</span></p>
  </body>
```

Comment: you have to convert price / age to integers to work properly. Eg use `parseInt()` before using price or age in calculate routine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, `price` is a string. Replace

```
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
```

with

```
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
```

The function has already worked for subtraction and division, because operators `-` and `/` can't be applied to strings, so JS coerces them to numbers. The `+`, however, has a string-compatible interpretation (string concatenation), so type coercion doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the case!

Answer (score 0):

or do this
 var price = Number(document.getElementById("price").value);

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the + symbol can be used both for numeric addition and string concatenation, depending on the variables either side. For example,

```
console.log('value:' + 4);           // 'value:4'
console.log(3 + 1);                   // 4
console.log('value:' + 4 + '+' + 1); // 'value:4+1'
console.log('value:' + 4 + 1);       // 'value:41'
console.log('value:' + (3 + 1));     // 'value:4'
console.log(4 + ' is the value');    // '4 is the value
```

Hence convert your operands to numeric type before proceeding with addition so that they are not concatenated.

Hope this clarifies.